# Where do I find the xctest bundle for EarlGrey?

Tags: automated-tests, earlgrey

As the title indicates, what's the path of the XCTest bundle generated by EarlGrey framework?

Answer (score 3):

I've [updated the EarlGrey FAQ](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/pull/99) with the xctest bundle location.

> ### Where do I find the xctest bundle?
>
> For the Example project, run the EarlGreyExampleSwiftTests target once
>   then find the bundle:
>
> cd
>   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EarlGreyExample-*/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EarlGreyExampleSwift.app/PlugIns/EarlGreyExampleSwiftTests.xctest/
>
> For physical device builds, replace Debug-iphonesimulator with
>   Debug-iphoneos.